PowerShell The WinRM client cannot process the request
hello so my code is the following:
$securePassword = $password |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $securePassword
Invoke-Command -FilePath "C:\Users\CompName\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\CloseWinCC.ps1" -ComputerName "CompName" -Credential $cred

Connecting to remote server "CompName" failed with the following error message :
The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if
the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.

I also tried running on localhost with the following code:
Invoke-Command -FilePath "C:\Users\CompName\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\CloseWinCC.ps1" -ComputerName localhost -Credential $cred

and yet even on localhost it gives the following error:
Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message :
Access is denied.
Any idea why?
update: I did run
Enable-PSRemoting - SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force

and now the error is :
Connecting to remote server CompName failed with the following error message : The WinRM
client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the
destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.


for localhost, are you running PowerShell as Admin?

You may need OAUTH2 credentials instead of Windows Credentials.  See https://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2014/projects/kanter-bcyphers-bfaviero-jpeebles.pdf

If not on a domain you may need to set LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy on the remote computer

I am not running powershell as admin for localhost but when I did try it output access is denied

This registry entry must be set for a non-domain account, and also running as administrator:
$path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System'
set-ItemProperty $path LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy 1 -Type DWord 

User Account Control and remote restrictions - Windows Server | Microsoft Learn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/user-account-control-and-remote-restriction#how-to-disable-uac-remote-restrictions

I am scared to enter registry and modify those. I am using computers at work so they are already fragile

You can always undo it.  If you have active directory, you don't need it.
